# SQL DataReader: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present to label

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqldatareader

I am trying to use a SqlDataReader to run queries on two tables where the 1st column in the Selection table is a foreign key referencing to the Items table, and then display the results in labels, but I keep getting the error:

> *Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.*

Here is my code:

```
public partial class Read : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"data source = localhost; integrated security = true; database = dev_handin1");
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        SqlDataReader rdr = null;
        string sqlsel = "SELECT MainItemId FROM Selection";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                GetInfo();
            }
        }

        private void GetInfo() {
            try
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlsel, conn);
                conn.Open();
                sqlsel = "SELECT * FROM Items WHERE ItemId = MyMainItem";
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                var MyMainItem = rdr[0];

                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        LabelCategory1.Text = rdr[1].ToString();
                        LabelHeadline1.Text = rdr[2].ToString();
                        LabelText1.Text = rdr[3].ToString();
                        LabelJoke1.Text = rdr[4].ToString();
                    }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LabelMessage1.Text = ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                rdr.Close();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm pretty new at this so please bear with me.

Comment: Do not do `select *` and after access the data using its position index. If the column order is not what you expected it will fail. It is better if you type the column names

Comment: You get this error because you access reader (`var MyMainItem = rdr[0]`) before advancing it (`rdr.Read()`) to the first record. You should call `rdr.Read()` at first and then access it (`rdr[0]`, `rdr[1]`, etc). See [SqlDataReader documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?view=netframework-4.8). What is the purpose of the method `GetInfo()`?.

Comment: Is the problem still persist?